# How to apply an action on elements with the same class added dynamically from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use Ajax to get some data from a Database , The returned data from that Ajax request :

```
<p class="fetchedData">First Result</p>
<p class="fetchedData">Second Result</p>
<p class="fetchedData">Third Result</p>
<p class="fetchedData">Fourth Result</p>
```

How can I get the text inside each `p` element  on clicking it?

Like when clicking on the `<p class="fetchedData">Fourth Result</p>` I get "Fourth Result".

I tried

```
var eachData $('.fetchedData').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click' , function(){
        console.log( $(this).text() );
    })
});
```

And

```
var allData = document.querySelectorAll('#fetchedData');
allData.forEach(function(el){
    console.log( $(this).text() );
}
```

But none of them worked .

Also I tried

```
$(document).on('click','.fetchedData' , function () {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
})
```

But it just works on the first element.

Comment: your `$(document).on`... works. see: https://jsfiddle.net/60nmexbh/1/

Comment: Last one should work

Comment: @HansZ , Yes thanks , I was using the id instead of class `<p id="">` and `$(document).on('click','#fetchedData' , function () {` , It has to be class not id

Comment: Your last one should work even with newly created elements see: https://jsfiddle.net/60nmexbh/10/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.fetchedData', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  })

  $.each(['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'], function(index, value) {
    $('body').append(`<p class="fetchedData">${value} Result</p>`);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need remove var eachData and just use jQuery each add click event

```
$('.fetchedData').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click' , function(){
       console.log( $(this).text() );
    })
});
```

Comment: Still not working , Please notice that the p elements are added from ajax request and they weren't exist when the page loaded

Comment: Yes , It is working now , This one works `$(document).on('click', '.fetchedData', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  })` , I was using id instead of class

Answer (score 0):

> http://api.jquery.com/html/

use .html()  click the above link for reference

or else use `document.getElementByClassName("className").value`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use an each loop if you have same class for every data. You can directly apply on click event over .fetchedData class.

```
$('.fetchedData').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```